# What is this succulent's name?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, perennials

I bought this from theheartcompany at metrotown. But i do not know the name of it, any answers?
[image: this succulent is what?]

Comment: You've got one now, soon you will have thousands! As they mature the entire leaf margin is covered in plantlets which drop off and try to establish.

Answer (score 3):

Note the plantlets on the leaf margins. This indicates that it is probably a Kalanchoe, possibly a "Mother of thousands" [*Bryophyllum daigremontianum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryophyllum_daigremontianum) or a hybrid Beechleaf Kalanchoe if the leaves are fuzzy.